# How to crawl href - Python & beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, href

I am currently crawling a web page (https://www.klook.com/city/30-kyoto/?p=1) using Python 3.4 and bs4 in order to collect the deeplinks of the respective activities.

I found that the links are located in the html source like this:

```
<a class="j_activity_item_link" href="/activity/1031-arashiyama-rickshaw-tour-kyoto/" class="j_activity_item_link" data-card-tags="{}" data-sold-out="false" data-price="40.0" data-city-id="30" data-id="1031" data-url-seo="arashiyama-rickshaw-tour-kyoto">
```

But after several trials, this `href="/activity/1031-arashiyama-rickshaw-tour-kyoto/"` never show up.

Here is my logic so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/43.0.2357'}

for page in range(1,6):
    r = requests.get("https://www.klook.com/city/30-kyoto" + "/?p=" +  str(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    g_data = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "j_activity_item_link"})
    for item in g_data:
        Deeplink = item.find_all("a")
        for t in Deeplink:
            print(t.get("href"))
```

Output:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Could you guys help me put? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly and include the _complete_ error message.

Comment: @DyZ thats my complete error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find the number of pages of activities, and then use regex with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
data = soup(str(urllib.urlopen('https://www.klook.com/city/30-kyoto/?p=1').read()), 'lxml')
page_numbers = [i.text for i in data.find_all('a', {'class':'p_num '})]
activities = {1:[i['href'] for i in data.find_all('a', {'href':re.compile("^/activity/")})]}
for page in page_numbers:
   data = soup(str(urllib.urlopen('https://www.klook.com/city/30-kyoto/?p={}'.format(page)).read()), 'lxml')
   activities[int(page)] = [i['href'] for i in data.find_all('a', {'href':re.compile("^/activity/")})]
```

Output:

```
{1: ['/activity/1079-one-day-kimono-rental-kyoto/', '/activity/1032-higashiyama-rickshaw-tour-kyoto/', '/activity/6128-kyoto-seaside-day-tour-osaka/', '/activity/1540-hankyu-1-day-tourist-pass-osaka/', '/activity/1777-icoca-ic-card-kyoto/', '/activity/1541-kix-airport-limousine-bus-transfer-kyoto/', '/activity/1753-randen-kyoto-bus-subway-1-day-pass-kyoto/', '/activity/3260-sagano-romantic-train-ticket-kyoto/', '/activity/793-japanese-lzakaya-cooking-course-kyoto/', '/activity/882-nishiki-market-teramachi-street-kyoto/', '/activity/792-morning-bento-cooking-course-kyoto/', '/activity/2918-sushi-class-experience-kyoto/', '/activity/6032-ninja-kyoto-restaurant-labyrinth-kyoto/', '/activity/5215-garden-ryokan-nanzenji-yachiyo-kyoto/', '/activity/1079-one-day-kimono-rental-kyoto/', '/activity/3260-sagano-romantic-train-ticket-kyoto/', '/activity/675-wifi-device-japan-kyoto/', '/activity/1031-arashiyama-rickshaw-tour-kyoto/', '/activity/657-day-trip-hiroshima-miyajima-kyoto/', '/activity/4774-4G-wifi-kyoto/', '/activity/2826-gionya-kimono-rental-kyoto/', '/activity/1464-kyoto-tower-admission-ticket-kyoto/', '/activity/2249-sagano-romantic-train-ticket-kyoto/', '/activity/1777-icoca-ic-card-kyoto/', '/activity/1541-kix-airport-limousine-bus-transfer-kyoto/', '/activity/1540-hankyu-1-day-tourist-pass-osaka/', '/activity/3532-wifi-device-japan-kyoto/', '/activity/1753-randen-kyoto-bus-subway-1-day-pass-kyoto/', '/activity/1319-4g-wifi-device-kyoto/', '/activity/1447-wi-ho-japan-wifi-device-kyoto/', '/activity/3826-wifi-device-japan-kyoto/', '/activity/2699-japan-wifi-device-taiwan-kyoto/', '/activity/3652-wifi-device-singapore-kyoto/', '/activity/1122-wi-ho-japan-wifi-device-kyoto/', '/activity/719-japan-docomo-sim-card-kyoto/', '/activity/6128-kyoto-seaside-day-tour-osaka/', '/activity/6241-nanzen-ji-fushimi-inari-taisha-sagano-romantic-train-day-tour/', '/activity/5137-guenpin-fugu-restaurant-kyoto/'], 2: ['/activity/1079-one-day-kimono-rental-kyoto/', '/activity/1032-higashiyama-rickshaw-tour-kyoto/', '/activity/6128-kyoto-seaside-day-tour-osaka/', '/activity/1540-hankyu-1-day-tourist-pass-osaka/', '/activity/1777-icoca-ic-card-kyoto/', '/activity/1541-kix-airport-limousine-bus-transfer-kyoto/', '/activity/1753-randen-kyoto-bus-subway-1-day-pass-kyoto/', '/activity/3260-sagano-romantic-train-ticket-kyoto/', '/activity/793-japanese-lzakaya-cooking-course-kyoto/', '/activity/882-nishiki-market-teramachi-street-kyoto/', '/activity/792-morning-bento-cooking-course-kyoto/', '/activity/2918-sushi-class-experience-kyoto/', '/activity/6032-ninja-kyoto-restaurant-labyrinth-kyoto/', '/activity/5215-garden-ryokan-nanzenji-yachiyo-kyoto/', '/activity/6543-arashiyama-golden-pavilion-temple-todaiji-kobe-mosaic-day-tour-kyoto/', '/activity/5198-nanzenji-junsei-restaurant-kyoto/', '/activity/7877-hanami-kimono-rental-kyoto/', '/activity/793-japanese-lzakaya-cooking-course-kyoto/', '/activity/9915-kyoto-osaka-sightseeing-pass-kyoto-japan/', '/activity/883-geisha-districts-tour-kyoto/', '/activity/1097-gion-kimono-experience-kyoto/', '/activity/6032-ninja-kyoto-restaurant-labyrinth-kyoto/', '/activity/792-morning-bento-cooking-course-kyoto/', '/activity/9272-4g-data-daijobu-sim-card-kyoto/', '/activity/871-sake-brewery-visit-fushimi-inari-shrine-kyoto/', '/activity/5979-tower-terrace-kyoto/', '/activity/632-kyoto-backstreet-cycling/', '/activity/646-kyoto-afternoon-exploration/', '/activity/640-kyoto-morning-sightseeing/', '/activity/872-arashiyama-bamboo-forest-half-day-tour-kyoto/', '/activity/5272-mukadeya-kyoto/', '/activity/6081-one-night-in-kyoto/', '/activity/2918-sushi-class-experience-kyoto/', '/activity/1032-higashiyama-rickshaw-tour-kyoto/', '/activity/5445-kimono-photo-shoot-kyoto/', '/activity/5215-garden-ryokan-nanzenji-yachiyo-kyoto/', '/activity/882-nishiki-market-teramachi-street-kyoto/', '/activity/7096-japan-prepaid-sim-card-kyoto/'], 3: ['/activity/1079-one-day-kimono-rental-kyoto/', '/activity/1032-higashiyama-rickshaw-tour-kyoto/', '/activity/6128-kyoto-seaside-day-tour-osaka/', '/activity/1540-hankyu-1-day-tourist-pass-osaka/', '/activity/1777-icoca-ic-card-kyoto/', '/activity/1541-kix-airport-limousine-bus-transfer-kyoto/', '/activity/1753-randen-kyoto-bus-subway-1-day-pass-kyoto/', '/activity/3260-sagano-romantic-train-ticket-kyoto/', '/activity/793-japanese-lzakaya-cooking-course-kyoto/', '/activity/882-nishiki-market-teramachi-street-kyoto/', '/activity/792-morning-bento-cooking-course-kyoto/', '/activity/2918-sushi-class-experience-kyoto/', '/activity/6032-ninja-kyoto-restaurant-labyrinth-kyoto/', '/activity/5215-garden-ryokan-nanzenji-yachiyo-kyoto/', '/activity/5271-itoh-dining-kyoto/', '/activity/9094-sagano-sightseeing-carriage-tour-kyoto/', '/activity/8192-japan-sim-card-taiwan-airport-pickup-kyoto/', '/activity/8420-south-korea-wifi-device-kyoto/', '/activity/8644-rock-climbing-at-kyoto-konpirayama-kyoto /', '/activity/9934-3g-4g-wifi-mnl-pick-up-delivery-for-japan-kyoto/', '/activity/8966-donburi-cooking-course-and-nishiki-market-tour-kyoto/', '/activity/9215-arashiyama-kyoto-food-drink-half-day-tour/']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your "error" of error code 0 simply indicates that everything went ok with your run. According to your example, your list `g_data` should contain all of the `a` tags that you are interested in. You should not need the second for loop to again iterate through and find nested `a` tags. As a debugging step, print the length of your lists to ensure that they are not empty. See the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/43.0.2357'}

for page in range(1,6):
    r = requests.get("https://www.klook.com/city/30-kyoto" + "/?p=" +  str(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    g_data = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "j_activity_item_link"})
    for item in g_data:
        print(item.get("href"))
```